# using React components in Reagent

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

I am trying to use components from http://react-components.com (eg. [react-youtube](http://react-components.com/component/react-youtube)) in Reagent based application, but probably my naive approach is not the right one. I tried to install NPM packages with `lein-npm` module, include script in html page and use them via `reagent/adapt-react-class` as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28759108/use-predefine-react-component-from-reagent) SO question. But for except this sample I wasn't successful.

Usually I get errors like "require/import/module is not defined" or "Youtube is undefined" (by having `(def yt-test [] (r/adapt-react-class js/Youtube))`. I am confused about what is needed to do. I read something about webpack/browserify, saw cljsjs packages - are those required in order to make this working?

Comment: In theory this should be simpler now: https://clojurescript.org/news/2017-07-12-clojurescript-is-not-an-island-integrating-node-modules but I'm not sure of some of the details. See also this test reagent project: https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent-site-npm-deps-test

Comment: Should have pointed at this pull request: https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent/pull/306

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those components are packaged as CommonJS modules.  One approach for accessing CommonJS modules from ClojureScript is to bundle them into a single JavaScript file that can be included with your ClojureScript build.

You'll need to create a JavaScript entry point file which requires your various NPM dependencies and exposes them to ClojureScript (for example, by setting them on `window`).  Create a file (let's call it `index.js`) containing:

```
window.YouTube = require('react-youtube');
```

Then use a tool like [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) to bundle your entry point file and all of the dependencies it requires:

```
npm install -g browserify
browserify index.js --standalone window > bundle.js
```

Include `bundle.js` in your ClojureScript build and you'll be able to access the React component from ClojureScript via `js/YouTube`

Comment: Looks to me like react-youtube is exported as a CommonJS module. https://github.com/troybetz/react-youtube/blob/master/src/YouTube.js

Comment: For other people - don't forget to remove direct import of package ([SO require not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28696511/require-is-not-defined-error-with-browserify)) and in case of that youtube player I had also to use `require("react-youtube").default`.

Answer (score 9):

I wrote a step by step guide on how to achieve this with webpack:
[blob.tomerweller.com/reagent-import-react-components-from-npm](http://blob.tomerweller.com/reagent-import-react-components-from-npm)

The general concept is the same as @scttnlsn suggested: bundle all npm packages in an external JS file and expose them through the global `window` object.

Comment: Thanks for this guide. I'm trying to adapt it for https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mathjax but don't know what to put in the view part as hiccup code? Do you have an idea?

Comment: Answering my own question:  `[:> ctx [:> node "2+2"]]`

Comment: I have another problem for which you could have a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45201315/a-is-undefined-when-compiling-a-cljs-prj-with-an-npm-module-under-prod-profil