# 'a is undefined' when compiling a cljs prj with an NPM module under :prod profile

Tags: compilation, clojurescript, cljsbuild

I followed this howto: http://blob.tomerweller.com/reagent-import-react-components-from-npm and it worked great. I even managed to use one of my own NPM module on top of this example app of re-frame: https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/tree/master/examples/simple/

Starting the resulting app with:

```
lein clean && lein figwheel
```

everything works ok, but when I do:

```
lein do clean, with-profile prod compile
```

I get a `TypeError: a is undefined`. Any idea to fix this?

Let me provide you with the code: the bad commit is [here](https://github.com/ClubExpressions/poc2/tree/bad),
while both `:dev` and `:prod` profiles work OK [at this just previous commit](https://github.com/ClubExpressions/poc2/tree/good).

**Update**: I managed to fix the compiled version like this (see [the commit](https://github.com/ClubExpressions/clubexpr-re-frame/commit/3872dbab088d1a36ea68a38ecb6d98c52ab7899d)):

```
  return d.c?d.c(c,v,w):d.call(null,c,v,w)}}(G,r,b,c,d,e)),I=dw(G);rf.b?: […]
  };w.b=v;w.c=f;return w}()}(c,d,e,f))};hf.b(ow,ik);hf.b(ow,bp);hf.b(ow,To); […]
  function nx(a){var b=window.deps["react-mathjax"],
-    c=window.deps.clubexpr.kf;
+    c=window.deps.clubexpr.renderLispAsLaTeX;
  return new U(null,3,5,V,[Vj,b.Context,new U(null,4,null)}
  function Wv(){return function(a){return function(){return new U(null,6,5,V,[…]
```

This seems to me a compilation misconfiguration or bug.

**Update 2**: my code compiles OK if I set `:optimizations` to `:simple` (was `:advanced`). See [the cljs compiler doc about this option](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Compiler-Options#optimizations).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The code that is failing is [here](https://github.com/ClubExpressions/poc2/commit/09e25b590ad75304be12c8358ad889443e070e0f#diff-d76b3cb59b2911089e4e94d783233a07R43).

It looks like you might need to provide [externs](https://github.com/cljsjs/packages/wiki/Creating-Externs) for clubexpr, so that the Closure Compiler knows not to rewrite `renderLispAsLatex` as `kf`. When compiling under :simple, the Closure Compiler doesn't rewrite function names, so this problem wouldn't show up.

As a side note, you probably shouldn't use `aget` to get objects from the window, `aget` is designed for array access only. To get objects, you should use `goog.object/get`. See this post on [Checked Array Access](https://clojurescript.org/news/2017-07-14-checked-array-access) for more info on this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and this very recent precious piece of information. However I'm not familiar with externs and didn't manage to use the online tool. Is my module correctly structured? https://clubexpressions.github.io/node-clubexpr/index.js

Comment: Not sure sorry, there's lots of info at https://github.com/cljsjs/packages/wiki/Creating-Externs.

Comment: OK, not much time to give it a try right now but I'll keep you update and vote/accept your answer accordingly. Thanks!